# SQL server 2012 : SQL query to get list of database for which a server is secondary in high availability configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can anyone please help me to get the SQL query to get list of databases for which a server is 
secondary . EX. in High availability group SERVER S1 is primary for availability group AV1(DB1,DB2) and  secondary for AV2 (DB3,DB4) .
I want query to get list of databases for which S1 is secondary ..here for DB3 and DB4.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will return a table containing database names of the databases that are in an availability group and are the secondary replicas on the queried server.

```
SELECT db.name FROM master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states rs
JOIN master.sys.databases db ON rs.database_id = db.database_id
WHERE is_local = 1 AND is_primary_replica = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have an exact query for you but it shouldn't be too hard to do, there are 2 DMVs to look at for this:

sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states - This will tell you about the availability groups and which servers are primary/secondary replicas for each

sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states - This will tell you about the databases within each availibility group and what state they are in

Join the two of these together on the group_id column and you will be able to see what databases are in which availability group and which servers are acting as primary/secondary replicas.

Links to the docs here:

[AlwaysOn Availability Groups Dynamic Management Views and Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877943.aspx)